# IP Table, what does this construct mean ::INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]

Tags: firewall, iptables, ip

I am looking at an IP Table construct, what does the following mean :

:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]

thanks

Comment: where did you get that output from? What command produced it?

Comment: @mulaz Probably from iptables-save.

Answer (score 5):

It means that the default policy for those three chains is ACCEPT, so all packets (in, out, and forwarded through your system) are 'accepted' (go through), and not firewalled (rejected or dropped).

Depending on the place where you got that, it might mean your current policy, or the default 'empty' policy for your system.

[more info here](http://wiki.vpslink.com/HOWTO:_Building_IPTables_rules)

Comment: Thanks Mulaz - so it negates the need to explicitly put the ACCEPT construct - smart...Is there a smart tool that allows you to dump in IP table firewall config and it will explain it in plain english ? I need to do some firewall rule analysis...

Comment: It depends on the setup. If you want blacklisting (allow all, deny just some IP's/connections), you leave the policy to ACCEPT, and add rules to block (iptables -A INPUT -s some.bad.ip.addr -j DROP)

Comment: If you want whitelisting (more secure, so "better"), you alow some IP's (iptables -A INPUT -s some.good.ip.addr -j ACCEPT), and then change the default policy to DROP (iptables -P INPUT DROP)

Comment: basically, you put a bunch of accept/drop/reject rules, and if the packet doesn't match any of them the default policy is applied (in your example, the packet is accepted). Sorry, for another comment, not enough coffee for a time like this

Comment: The 0:0 is a byte and packet counter.

Answer (score 1):

Here All the Chains [INPUT, OUTPUT, FORWARD] has response - ACCEPT. in general , whatever the data or pockets passing from INPUT, OUTPUT AND FORWARD chains are accepted; whereas [0:0] means from all networks to all networks.