# Why do I need a specific port 80 rule inspite of having :INPUT ACCEPT [0:0] in /etc/sysconfig/iptables?

Tags: linux, firewall, iptables

On my RHEL 6.2 server, in my /etc/sysconfig/iptables, I have `:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]` but I cannot access files through web server on port 80 unless I add a rule like this:

```
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

Please clarify why. Thanks. According to [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/385513/ip-table-what-does-this-construct-mean-input-accept-00/397004#397004), I shouldn't need that additional entry.

Comment: What rules are defined in the output table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can only guess as you don't show us the rest of your INPUT rules. My guess is that you have a line like this

```
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
```

at the end of your input rules. This will reject any packet that arrives there and so your policy (`:INPUT ACCEPT`)isn't consulted.

Comment: Yup! That's exactly what it is. I didn't know what that line meant. Here's the full content of iptables file.
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
COMMIT

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to paste the iptables content so that it shows on different lines.